# D7200 no longer autofocusing

Tags: nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting, focus, camera-settings

AF on the body of the camera

M/A on the lens

Back dial is not locked

I've tried clicking and holding the AE-L/AF-L button

Tried two different lenses

Battery is full

In the viewfinder, I see two arrows facing each other, sometimes one is showing, sometimes both. Can't seem to change from AFS, to AFA or AFC

Tried cleaning electrical contacts on both the body and lens.

I didn't change anything from one day to the next... it just stopped working. I did get a replacement 50MM Nikkor 1.8G lens, I put it on somewhat hastily with a bit of difficulty; it wasn't sliding in like the other lenses, but it did click in. Maybe that's what messed it up.

Can't seem to factory reset either by holding down exposure and iso.

At a loss for what's wrong

[image]

Comment: Try resetting your custom settings. Examine your A4: AF setting in particular. Try reloading your firmware.

Comment: @user10216038 No luck tinkering with either unfortunately

Comment: When you say "M/A on the lens", which is it set at? "M" or "A"?

Comment: Nikons have M/A & M - one is switchable in-body, the other is manual only.

Comment: I saw this: **https://ekatibah.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/nikon-d300-refuses-to-autofocus-and-the-solve/** . Net result suggests switching to Live View then back.

Comment: Also this: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEDzAMm1FCc**

Answer (score 2):

If Auto ISO is selecting ISO 25600 at f/1.8 and 1/50 seconds, that means the light you are shooting in is *VERY* dim. It is equivalent to proper exposure for about EV -1.

It might not be enough light for the AF system on your D7200 to function properly, particularly if your focus target does not have a strong amount of contrast. Even though the AF system of your D7200 is rated to function down to EV -3, that rating is measured using a target with alternating white and black lines that provide plenty of contrast. The combination of low light and a low contrast target could be more than the AF system can handle, even if the light is slightly brighter than EV -3.

Comment: I should have removed the lens cap before I took a photo of the info panel here. Unfortunately it’s not the lighting as I’ve tried in bright daylight

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a D7200 and it was the small locking pin on the camera mount had stopped coming out so the lens would not lock onto the camera and this prevented AF .I also couldnt reset the camera.
I managed to resolve this and it now AF's correctly.